# Почему происходит ошибка "Error: Could not find or load main class Main"?

Tags: java

Есть простенький код:

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.print("Enter your name:");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Hello," + scan.nextLine() + "!");
    }
}
```

При помощи `javac` данный код получается файл `Main.class`. Когда пытаюсь запустить при помощи `java Main` в этой же папке выдаёт ошибку:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Main
```

Comment: код выглядит корректным, пишите в деталях как вы это компилируете конкретно, какой вывод получаете, как вы это запускаете. Чтобы мы могли ваши шаги повторить и увидеть вашу ошибку.

Comment: В текущей папке такого класса нет.

Comment: скачай ide и пиши в ней , не заморачивайся с консолью, потом если надо будет разберёшся.

Comment: а PATН прописан в настройках "Переменные среды"?

Comment: может полное имя давать ```com.company.Main```

Comment: когда запускаете при помощи java, вы находитесь в директории с файлом Main.class?

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте вот так:

```
java -classpath . com.company.Main
```

Answer (score 0):

Когда-то давно у меня была такая же ошибка, и вот как я решил проблему.

#### Решение проблемы

Командную строку надо запускать из **корня проекта**, а не из папки, в которой лежит ваш класс. В вашем случае корень проекта - это та папка, в которой находится папка `com`. Но компилировать тогда нужно будет так:

```
javac com/company/Main.java
```

А запускать так:

```
java com/company/Main
```

#### На будущие

А вообще лучше поставить среду разработки, в ней нужно просто нажать кнопку "run", чтобы скомпилировать и запустить программу.

Comment: а чтобы просто пользоваться готовой программой, тоже лучше поставить среду разработки?

Comment: @Эникейщик судя по тому, что у автора есть код (кстати код довольно простой), автор вопроса не пользуется готовой программой, а пишет свои (ну то есть учит java).